# Graphql Parent data filtering by Child resolver

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

**Problem statement:**

Customer has multiple policies. we need to filter the customer based on policy statuses.

Our graphql schema like this :

```
customersByPolicyStatusCriteria(
    status: [String!]!
): CustomerSearchResult!

type CustomerSearchResult {
    dataset: [Customer]
}

type Customer {
    clientNumber: ID!
    name: CustomerName
    policies(status: [String]): [CustomerPolicy]
}
```

As in schema , In the parent we need to filter out based on policy status. Once receive the parent data and  again we need to filter out in the child resolver.  So it is kind of redundant operation to achieve the correct result :

**example** : Cx-Customer Px- PolicyStatus  C1(P1,P2) C2(P3,P1,P2) C3(P3) => (filter based on (P1,P2) ) =>  Expected : C1(P1,P2) C2(P1,P2)

Currently i am facing two sub problem in this case :

> case 1: If i remove the parent filter => I will receive all customers
> (without policy detail) who are not contain required policy status. ( eg C1(P1,P2),C2(P1,P2),C3(null))
>
> Case 2: if i remove the child filter => I ll receive all policies
> which are not in the required status (eg C1(P1,P2), C2(P3,P1,P2))

I am new to the graphql. need to explore following options :

1. Modify the schema
2. Graphql Join
3. remove the parent node(Customer) as soon as some condition happens in the child resolver (PolicyResolver)

Any suggestion solve this problem effectively ?